# update minDate and maxDate of two JQuery datepicker in AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I created two directive for my to input fields start_at and end_at, to display JQuery datepicker

PLUNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/s71WDURou0QlRzM8Kjkc?p=preview

JS:

```
app.directive("startDateCalendar", [
  function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      return element.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        defaultDate: scope.campaign.start_at,
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect: function(date) {
          scope.campaign.start_at = date;
          scope.$apply();
        }
      });
    };
  }
]).directive("endDateCalendar", [
  function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      return element.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: scope.campaign.start_at,
        defaultDate: scope.campaign.end_at,
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect: function(date) {
          scope.campaign.end_at = date;
          return scope.$apply();
        }
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" start-date-calendar ng-model="campaign.start_at" />
<input type="text" end-date-calendar ng-model="campaign.end_at" />
```

What I would like to happen:

- when user updated the `campaign.start_at`, the minDate of `campaign.end_at` will be `campaign.start_at`
- when user updated the `campaign.end_at`, the maxDate of `campaign.start_at` will be `campaign.end_at`

I have tried using AngularJS UI Datepicker, which works well however I need an option to display 2 months in the picker which made me switch to JQuery Datepicker instead.

Comment: Which datepicker are you using?

Comment: I am using JQuery datepicker. I just updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: you can use same dropdown toggle for both datepickers to open or have a look at [date-range-picker for angular](http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/)

Comment: @HarishR please see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/s71WDURou0QlRzM8Kjkc?p=preview to see what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

For those encountering the same issue; I used `$watch` to update min and max of my datepicker; Here is the working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/s71WDURou0QlRzM8Kjkc?p=preview